# Filter empty buckets from aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, bucket

So, we trying to filter those empty buckets retrieved from ElasticSearch, with no success.

With the aggregation, we can find: for each vehicle color, for each timestamp, the sum of manufacturing hours.

At the last section, we wrote a script which finds aggregation exceeded 1000 hours of manufacturing.

It works. Unfortunately we receiving an **empty buckets** instead of those filtered results lower than 1000.

Here is our query:

```json
    {
     "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
      "colors": {
       "terms": {
        "field": "color"
        "min_doc_count": 1
       },
       "aggs": {
        "timestamps": {
         "terms": {
          "field": "timestamp",
          "min_doc_count": 1
         },
         "aggs": {
          "sum_manufacturing": {
           "sum": {
            "field": "hours"
           }
          },
          "manufacturing_bucket_filter": {
           "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
             "hours": "sum_manufacturing"
            },
            "script": {
             "inline": "hours > 1000",
             "lang": "expression"
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

You will notice that we added 'min_doc_count' here and there - but it won't do the trick.

Here is an empty bucket retrieved as a result:

```json
    {
      "key": "Yellow",
      "doc_count": 336,
      "timestamps": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 332,
        "buckets": [

        ]
      }
    }
```

And an UN-empty bucket:

```json
    {
      "key": "Blue",
      "doc_count": 336,
      "timestamps": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 332,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 1464880946000,
            "key_as_string": "2016-06-02T15:22:26.000Z",
            "doc_count": 4,
            "sum_manufacturing": {
              "value": 1049
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

It would be great if there is a way to filter **out** empty buckets.
Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```json
    {
     "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
      "colors": {
       "terms": {
        "field": "color"
        "min_doc_count": 1
       },
       "aggs": {
        "timestamps": {
         "terms": {
          "field": "timestamp",
          "min_doc_count": 1
         },
         "aggs": {
          "sum_manufacturing": {
           "sum": {
            "field": "hours"
           }
          },
          "manufacturing_bucket_filter": {
           "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
             "hours": "sum_manufacturing"
            },
            "script": {
             "inline": "hours > 1000",
             "lang": "expression"
            }
           }
          },
          "min_bucket_selector":{
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {"count": "sum_manufacturing._bucket_count"},
                "script": {"inline": "params.count != 0"}
              }
            }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

I think this might solve your issue.